# Как подсунуть кастомную cookie в curl в процессе работы

Tags: php, cookie, curl

При работе curl использую параметры которые автоматически отслеживают установку/отдачу cookie следующим образом:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'path_to_file');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'path_to_file');
```

В процессе работы одного сеанса curl мне нужно ему подсунуть кастомную куку. Собственно попытался это сделать следующим образом:

```
$headers[] = 'Cookie: foo=val';
//дальше заголовки скармливаю curl
```

но возникла проблема, в заголовках запроса появляется второй заголовок с именем Cookie, который принимающим сервером судя по всему не обрабатывается. Посоветуйте, что можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'foo=val');`

Насколько помню, конфликтов с `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` и `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` быть не должно.

Как вариант можно ещё записать в конец файла указанного в `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` нужные значения перед инициализацией сессии.

Comment: что то совсем забыл про эту опцию, все работает!